# Custom Fiori error when accessed from launchpad but not from SE80 (direct BSP test)

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I am working on a custom fiori project, when I try to test directly from BSP via the SE80 tcode and click test, Fiori runs well. But when I deploy it to launchpad there is an error.

I got an error **"adding element with duplicate id 'App'."**

This error has indeed happened but I have fixed it and according to BSP through SE80 there are no more errors.

My question is, Is there a cache that hasn't been updated from the launchpad side? How I can fix it ? Please Help Thanks...

Comment: have you flushed the browser cache (e.g. in Chrome hit F12 and then right click on the refresh button and select appropriately)

Comment: Yes I have done that, Using F12 and Empty Cache and Hard Reload.. but the errorr still occurs

Comment: Have you thought of renaming the Id so that it does not conflict with something on Launchpad?

Comment: Hi.. Bernard thanks for help. I got the answer from other user to clear the cache using this link https://blogs.sap.com/2017/12/22/cache-cleanup-in-sap-netweaver-gateway/ and its works.